# DataBound Dependency Property is not updating when source value changes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a custom button that has a boolean property which I am trying to bind to an instance of a model. Everything appears to be correct but it's not catching the property changes...

To be clear the relationship I want to happen is that `MyControl.BooleanProperty` updates to match `Source.BooleanProperty` when `Source.BooleanProperty` changes.

```
<Window
    ...
    xmlns:p="clr-namespace:FooProject.Properties"
    DataContext="{x:Static p:Settings.Default}">
    <MyControls:GlassButton        
        Pulsing="{Binding Pulse}"/>
</Window>
```

Within the application settings lies a property called "Pulse" ( boolean property ).

This is the relevant source code for my control :

```
public class GlassButton : Button {
    #region Dependency Properties           
    public static readonly DependencyProperty
        //A whooole lot of irrelevant stuff...
        PulsingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Pulsing", typeof(bool), typeof( GlassButton ),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( false ) ),
        //Lots more irrelevant stuff

    [Category("Pulse")]
    public bool Pulsing{
        get{ return ( bool )( this.GetValue( PulsingProperty ) );
        set{
            if ( value )
                this.BeginAnimation( BackgroundProperty, this._baPulse );
            else
                this.BeginAnimation( BackgroundProperty, null );    
            this.SetValue( PulsingProperty, value );
        }
    }
    //And a pile of more irrelevant stuff.
```

I have breakpoints set at the `Pulsing` setter but they never get hit...

It's behaving consistently, whether in a bare-bones application like this one, or in an actual honest to goodness real application...

Why is the binding not taking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not rely on instance setter to get property updates. Because data binding works around these instance property setters. To get property updates from data binding you should provide `PropertyChangedCallback` to `PropertyMetadata` when you register property. Like this:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PulsingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Pulsing", typeof (bool), typeof (GlassButton), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnPulsingPropertyChanged));

    //keep it clean
    public bool Pulsing
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool) GetValue(PulsingProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(PulsingProperty, value);
        }
    }

    //here you get your updates
    private static void OnPulsingPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var glassButton = (GlassButton)d;
        var newPulsingValue = (bool)e.NewValue;
        if (newPulsingValue)
            glassButton.BeginAnimation( BackgroundProperty, glassButton._baPulse );
        else
            glassButton.BeginAnimation( BackgroundProperty, null );
    }
```

Comment: Hm... that's interesting I'll have to look at that but yes, that makes sense... thanks.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks very much ( I hate myself ).